# How to get multiple source files for a command line java application

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am writing a command line java application and planning to use a library to parse the command line options.
and I want to take multiple file names as input.

For now I have chosen apache commons-cli (1.2).
My main method is as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("s", "source", true, "file(s) as input");

    CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
    CommandLine input = null;
    try{
        input = parser.parse(options, args);
    }catch (ParseException e){
        new HelpFormatter().printHelp("Usage: ", options);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String [] files = null;
    if(input.hasOption("s")){
        files = input.getOptionValues("s");         
    }
 }
```

Now when I execute the program with arguments `"-s /home/keshava/file1  /home/keshava/file2"`
I get only one file in files array.

I know I can get multiple files by `"-s /home/keshava/file1  -s /home/keshava/file2"`
But I dont want to do that.

Is there a way to specify a value separator in any way? 
Any other library suggestion is also ok.

Thanks,
Keshava

Comment: it is 2105 use a modern args parser like [JewelCLI](http://jewelcli.lexicalscope.com/) or at least [JSAP](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/) that apache commons crap is just that crap always has been and just gets crappier with time.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer, you can get multiple values in the array by specifying the maximum number of values for a given option supports using the `setArgs()` method.

```
Options options = new Options();
Option option = new Option("s", "source", true, "file(s) as input");
// Let option s take up to 5 arguments
option.setArgs(5);
options.addOption(option);
```

The `setArgs()` method also accepts `Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES` when the maximum number of values does not have a fixed limit.

Answer (score 0):

If using `OptionBuilder`, the method `hasArgs()` can be applied to the builder, optionally with the limit. Without no limit specified it will use `Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES`.

```
// Unlimited
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("file(s)").hasArgs().withLongOpt("files").create("f"));

// Limit to 5
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("file(s)").hasArgs(5).withLongOpt("files").create("f"));
```